# How can I make SSIS detect the record length when importing a flat file?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I wrote an SSIS package which imports data from a fixed record length flat file into a SQL table. Within a single file, the record length is constant, but different files may have different record lengths. Each record ends with a CR/LF. How can I make it detect where the end of the record is, and use that length when importing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not work for everyone, but what I ended up doing was simply setting it to a delimited flat file and setting CR/LF as the row delimiter, and leaving the column delimiter and text qualifier blank. This won't work if you actually need to have it split out columns in the import, but I was already using a Derived Column task to do the actual column splitting, because my column positions are variable, so it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a script task. Pass a ReadWriteVariable into the script task. Let's call the ReadWriteVariable intLineLength. In the script task code, detect the location of the CR/LF and write it to intLineLength. Use the intLineLength ReadWriteVariable in following package steps to import the data.

Here is an article with some good examples: [script-task-to-dynamically-build-package-variables](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1443/integration-services-script-task-to-dynamically-build-package-variables/)

Hope this helps.